# jquery scrollTo not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, scroll, scrollto

I'm just trying to scroll to a specific DOM element or absolute position in my browser window, and it's not working. Here's my code:

```
$(window)._scrollable();
$('#scene_01_down').click(function(){
    $(window).scrollTo(2000,1000);
});
```

and here's the documentation for the plugin:

http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Do you really need that plugin?

```
$("html,body").animate({
    scrollTop: 2000,
    scrollLeft: 1000
});
```

To scroll to a particular element:

```
var offset = $("#someElement").offset();
$("html,body").animate({
    scrollTop: offset.top,
    scrollLeft: offset.left
});
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/ZdKyk/)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to repeat with mine - plus, I like your version better :)

Comment: I hate it when people don't answer the question.  But this did a good job & I've always hated that plugin :)